# How do I convert a float datatype column, displayed in e notation format, to integer in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scientific-notation

This is the column, [image], and when i try `med_app['patient_id'].astype(int)` it results in a negative output like so, [image].
I want the output in this format; 2.987250e+13 to 29872499824296

Comment: Paste your code instead of images

Comment: Try `.astype('uint64')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max size int32 is `2**31 - 1 = 2147483647 ≈ 2.147e9`. If you want ints larger than this, you should use int64, which has max size `2**63 - 1 = 9223372036854775807 ≈ 9.2233e+18`. When I test this myself, it automatically chooses int64 when I perform `.astype(int)`, but you can be explicit and do `.astype(np.int64)` (when you `import numpy as np`). If you need to go even larger, you can use uint64, which goes all the way up to `2 ** 64 ≈ 1.845e+19`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you check the type of column without any type conversion the column would still be of type `int`, what you are seeing is just the pandas display format which by default uses scientific notation for extremely large/small numbers.

If you wish to visualise the numbers as stored then you just need to set appropriate pandas display option.

`med_app[["patient_id"]].style.format("{:.0f}")`